# Python Regex, Match multiple substrings

Tags: python, regex, substring

We have a dictionary of dictionaries that look like this:

```
    modelRE = {
       'APPLE':
            {
                'MAC MINI MA206LL/A': re.compile(r'^(?=.*\bMAC\b)(?=.*\bMINI\b)(?=.*\bMA206LL/A\b).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE),
                'MAC MINI MC816LL/A': re.compile(r'^(?=.*\bMAC\b)(?=.*\bMINI\b)(?=.*\bMC816LL/A\b).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE),
                'MACBOOK AIR MD760LL/A': re.compile(r'^(?=.*\bMACBOOK\b)(?=.*\bAIR\b)(?=.*\bMD760LL/A\b).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE),
                'MACBOOK AIR LINE': re.compile(r'^(?=.*\bMACBOOK\b)(?=.*\bAIR\b).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE),
                'MACBOOK PRO MC024LL/A': re.compile(r'^(?=.*\bMACBOOK\b)(?=.*\bPRO\b)(?=.*\bMC024LL/A\b).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE),
                'MACBOOK PRO MD10xLL/A': re.compile(r'^(?=.*\bMACBOOK\b)(?=.*\bPRO\b)(?=.*\bMD10xLL/A\b).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE),
                'MACBOOK PRO ME293LL/A': re.compile(r'^(?=.*\bMACBOOK\b)(?=.*\bPRO\b)(?=.*\bME293LL/A\b).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE),
                'MACBOOK PRO ME294LL/A': re.compile(r'^(?=.*\bMACBOOK\b)(?=.*\bPRO\b)(?=.*\bME294LL/A\b).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE),
                'MACBOOK PRO ME86xLL/A': re.compile(r'^(?=.*MACBOOK)(?=.*PRO)(?=.*ME86xLL/A).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE),
                'MACBOOK PRO MF840LL/A': re.compile(r'^(?=.*\bMACBOOK\b)(?=.*\bPRO\b)(?=.*\bMF840LL/A\b).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE),
                'MACBOOK PRO MJLT2LL/A': re.compile(r'^(?=.*\bMACBOOK\b)(?=.*\bPRO\b)(?=.*\bMJLT2LL\/A\b).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE),
                'MACBOOK PRO Z0QN': re.compile(r'^(?=.*\bMACBOOK\b)(?=.*\bPRO\b)(?=.*\bZ0QN\b).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE),
                'MACBOOK PRO LINE': re.compile(r'^(?=.*\bMACBOOK\b)(?=.*\bPRO\b).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)
            },
.
.
.
```

But something is definitely wrong with our regex approach, you can see some experimenting going on here. This document is about 7000 lines, so I'd like to keep the regex approach consistent each time it's defined.

Basically, we are normalizing model numbers here on 700,000 rows of computers, restricted by an already normalized manufacturer.

We also have lines like this (another experiment):

```
'ELITEBOOK 2760P': re.compile(r'^(?=.*\b2760P\b)(Elite).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE),
```

To make a long story short, we are looking to match multiple substrings in every regex. For the regex to return true when we '.search' it, it must contain those substrings in any order.

For example (pseudo regex):

```
substring(MAC) && substring(MINI) && substring(MA206LL/A) IN ANY ORDER
```

This should match:

```
'MAC MINI MA206LL/A'
'MINI MAC MA206LL/A'
'MACMINI MA206LL/A'
'MAC-MINI-MA206LL/A'
'BIGMACandFRIES-MINI-MA206LL/A'
'MAC MINIMOUSE MA206LL/A'
'MAC MINI MA206LL/A-R321'
```

Comment: Actually, the flags should be `|`-ed.

Comment: But that's OR... we need AND.

Comment: it's unclear how are you applying all those patterns, by which order, for what input?

Comment: Order is unimportant, we want them to be in any or... here is the question restated: "In python I can do 'if (a in d and b in d and c in d)' assuming all variables are strings. How do I do that with regex... i'll delete the question if you think I should, but any help appreciated.

Comment: @user3656612 - The `|` is what lets you set multiple flags

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do some string checking?

```
foo = 'MAC '
bar = 'MINI'
baz = 'MA206LL/A'

for item in modelRE['APPLE']:
    if foo in item and bar in item and baz in item:
        print(item)
```

Comment: Yeah... this is my preferred approach. But the boss seems set on regex for whatever reason. I guess the main reason is that it uses dictionaries... so you can separate 'what to compare' from the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do an effective contains and contains.

re.compile('^(?=.*ACE)(?=.*4710).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)